# Adding filters to CIImage

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, ciimage

I creating an application for work with images, but I encountered a problem. I can not add filters to a photo and I do not know how to solve this problem.

I wrote own class for work with CIImage:

```
import CoreImage

typealias Filter = (CIImage) -> ()
typealias ParametersFilter = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

public protocol PXImageDelegate {
   func updateImage(picker: PXImage)
}

public class PXImage: CIImage {

public var delegate: PXImageDelegate?

open var brightness: Float = 0 {
    willSet (value) {
        brightness = value
        brightness(value)(self)
        updateImage()
    }
}

open var contrast: Float = 1 {
    willSet (value) {
        contrast = value
        contrast(value)(self)
        updateImage()
    }
}

open var saturation: Float = 1 {
    willSet (value) {
        saturation = value
        saturation(value)(self)
        updateImage()
    }
}

private func brightness(_ value: Float) -> Filter {
    return { image in
        let parameters: ParametersFilter = [
            kCIInputBrightnessKey: value as AnyObject,
            kCIInputImageKey: image
        ]

        self.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: parameters)
    }
}

private func contrast(_ value: Float) -> Filter {
    return { image in
        let parameters: ParametersFilter = [
            kCIInputContrastKey: value as AnyObject,
            kCIInputImageKey: image
        ]

        self.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: parameters)
    }
}

private func saturation(_ value: Float) -> Filter {
    return { image in
        let parameters: ParametersFilter = [
            kCIInputSaturationKey: value as AnyObject,
            kCIInputImageKey: image
        ]

        self.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: parameters)
    }
}

func updateImage() {
    delegate?.updateImage(picker: self)
}
```

But when I changed values of brightness, contrast and saturation nothing happens. The picture remains static. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look at the method signature for [CIImage.applyingFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1437589-applyingfilter).  It is not a mutating method; it returns a new CIImage.  Second the way that CIImage works is that its basically storing the image + the shader instructions for the filter.  It does not actually compile and execute the shader(s) until you either implcitly (for example by converting to UIImage) or explicily create a CIContext.  I can't tell if you are doing this or not since I can;t see your code.  In anycase you should ahve a chain of filters who's inputs are controlled by your parameters.  You then simply reevaluate the filters when any parameter is changed.

Comment: Thank your for your reply! I am drawing this image inside GLKView using CIContext.